# Load SVG file on JPanel with batik

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik

I want to load an SVG-file on a JPanel with this simple code but the JPanel is grey. Do i something wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas;


public class SVGApplication extends JPanel
{
     public SVGApplication(){


          JSVGCanvas svg = new JSVGCanvas();
          // location of the SVG File
          svg.setURI("file:/C:/Users/Linda/Desktop/test.svg");
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          panel.add(svg);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("SVGView");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.getContentPane().add(new SVGApplication());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setSize(500, 400);
          frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding things to a JPanel, one here named "panel", that gets added to nothing and so is never displayed:

```
 public SVGApplication(){
      JSVGCanvas svg = new JSVGCanvas();
      // location of the SVG File
      svg.setURI("file:/C:/Users/Linda/Desktop/test.svg");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // *** what is this for? ***
      panel.add(svg);  // **** you never add this panel to anything ****
 }
```

Get rid of panel:

```
 public SVGApplication(){
      JSVGCanvas svg = new JSVGCanvas();
      // location of the SVG File
      svg.setURI("file:/C:/Users/Linda/Desktop/test.svg");
      // JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // *** what is this for? ***
      // panel.add(svg);
      add(svg);
 }
```

Better still, why not simply use a JSVGCanvas component? Why wrap it in your SVGApplication panel?